# JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject Value ["1"]

Tags: android, json, android-studio, kotlin, android-volley

I have created JSONRequest by using volley ussing this tutorial https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-use-volley-library-to-parse-json-in-android-kotlin-app

Blynk APi returns this **"1"**

i have this error **Caused by: org.json.JSONException: Value ["1"] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject**

```
private fun jsonParse() {
    val url = "http://blynk-cloud.com/4ae3851817194e2596cf1b7103603ef8/get/D8"
    val request = JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, { response ->
        try {
            val JSONObject = response.getJSONArray("test")
            for (i in 0 until JSONObject.length()) {
                val test = JSONObject.getJSONObject(i)
                val status = test.getString("test1")
                textView.append("$status")
            }
        } catch (e: JSONException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }, { error -> error.printStackTrace() })
    requestQueue?.add(request)
}
```

Comment: Right now you have this response from the API ["1"].

But according to your code, you should have a response that looks sth like this 
{"test":[{"test1":"some text here"}]}

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, the response JSON string is not correct. I checked the JSON string with the Url on Firefox, it shows:
[image: error JSON]

Use this style JSON to test is nonsense, I think. If you want to test parsing JSON with Volley lib, you can use public API to test it.